Why does my ros2 node look for data inside /install folder instead of src/foo/resource/data folder?
I created a ros2 node in python, and it calls for data inside rrt_trajectory_JERK.csv. This file is saved inside ros2ws/src/foo_package/resource/data/ folder but the node couldn't find the script despite using those helper function to read out the data:
@staticmethod
def get_file_location(filename, location='data'):
    directory_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))), location)
    os.makedirs(directory_path, exist_ok=True)
    return os.path.join(directory_path, filename)

def read_data(filename, order=-1, dimensions=-1):
    filename = get_file_location(filename, 'resource/data')
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return read_file(file, order, dimensions)

@staticmethod
def read_file(file, order=-1, dimensions=-1):
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    data_list = list(reader)
    data_array = np.array(data_list).astype(np.float64)
    return data_array[:, order:order+dimensions] if order > -1 and dimensions > -1 else data_array

The helper functions is on the same directory as the ros node.
This is the error message i get:
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py:146: UserWarning: A NumPy version >=1.17.3 and <1.25.0 is required for this version of SciPy (detected version 1.26.4
  warnings.warn(f"A NumPy version >={np_minversion} and <{np_maxversion}"
OIAC controller
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/ros2ws/install/ros_package/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resource/data/rrt_trajectory_JERK.csv'

The problem caused by that my node is looking for the script inside ~/ros2ws/install/ros_package/lib/python3.10/site-packages/resource/data/ and not in ~/ros2ws/src/foo_package/resource/data/
Why does this happen, is there a solution to this?

This is used to separate src files from resources. There are also other reasons why this is used. If you really want to use data inside src folder, you could add something like that to your script:
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
file_path = os.path.join(cwd,'src/foo_package/resource/data/rrt_trajectory_JERK.csv')

The suggested way is to install the directory in the share folder using your setup.py and then accessing it.
